# AngularJS/Django & Forms server-side validation result

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have an html form that is generated automatically in Django, displayed as a modal window using Bootstrap UI and needs to be posted via ajax with Angular.

The problem is that some validations happen on the server-side and in case of an error I need to display any errors the same way I would if it were full http post (e.g. return the form with the invalid user input in red highlighting and errors next to each field).

I'm trying to avoid to write a custom response in my view and custom parsing in my script per case as I have quite a lot of forms that require validation and need to be submitted in a modal window.

Any help really appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code:

Form

```
from django import forms
from djangular.forms import NgFormValidationMixin
from djangular.styling.bootstrap3.forms import Bootstrap3Form


class FormBase(Bootstrap3Form, NgFormValidationMixin, forms.Form):
    form_name = None


class AppRequestForm(FormBase):
    form_name = 'app_request_form'
    class_type = AppRequest

    name = forms.RegexField(
        r'^.*$',
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'ng-model': 'request.name'}),
        error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid name.'}
    )

    email = forms.RegexField(
        r'^.*$',
        label='Email',
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'ng-model': 'request.email'}),
        error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid email.'}
    )
```

View

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from public.forms import AppRegisterForm, AppRequestForm


class ViewBase(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(theme=THEME_PATH)
        kwargs.update(page=self.request.resolver_match.url_name)
        return super(ViewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


class FormViewBase(ViewBase, FormView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(form=self.get_form())
        return super(FormViewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.success_action(form)
        return super(FormViewBase, self).form_valid(form)


class AppRequest(FormViewBase):
    template_name = 'public/app_request.html'
    form_class = AppRequestForm

    def success_action(self, form):
        # persist data
```

Template:

```
<form name="{{ form.form_name }}" method="post" action="/app/request" class="form" validate>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Request details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
            <fieldset>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_div }}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(request)" ng-disabled="{{ form.form_name }}.$invalid">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$scope.apps.request = function (id) {
    var url = '/app/request';
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: url,
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance, state) {
            $scope.submit = function (request) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: state.url,
                    data: $.param(request),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // Display validation errors on the modal window and allow user to re-submit
                });
            };
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            state: function () {
                return {
                    scope: $scope,
                    url: url,
                    id: id
                };
            }
        }
    });
};
```